# Can i fetch user profile by using client_id and client_secret of Azure Oauth app?

Tags: azure, validation, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have requirement where i have to store `client_id` and `client_secret` in database, before storing in database i have to validate given `client_id` and `client_secret`, If i am able to fetch username by `client_id` and `client_secret` than i can compare user given username and username from Microsoft if both are matching than i am good to store in database.

Note : I can fetch userprofile by using `access_token` but this is not i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to fetch user profile using `client_id` and
`client_secret` using application only permissions. To  achieve this you need to use [Client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) and [MS Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

Since,

1. The client credential flow  does not require User login.
2. MS Graph supports Application permissions for the user. Please refer [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Please go through the [Github sample](https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2) which can help to achieve the same.